# Issue with array formula and parsing array into database

Tags: php, arrays, forms, mysqli, billing

i am creating a form to do billing and i had a fatal error on the total_amt_array. Also, how do i parse an array of items into database? The form is in the Create Invoice and the invoicesubmit is where it adds all the arrays into the database. Anyone can explain to me why i can't make a total sum of the discount, amount and quantity array.

Also, does anyone have an easier way to calculate all of the total_amt_array. I've searched stackoverflow and others find the final total amount by adding the entire cost column to get the final total cost amount.

Create Invoice

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>


<script type="text/javascript">

var count = 0;


function addTextArea(){
count= count+1;
var div = document.getElementById('name');
div.innerHTML += "<div> <input type='text' name='name[]' value='' "+"id=name"+count+"> </div>";
div.innerHTML += "\n<br />";
var div = document.getElementById('quantity');
div.innerHTML += "<div><input type='text' name='quantity[]' value ='' "+"id=quantity"+count+"></div>";
div.innerHTML += "\n<br />";
var div = document.getElementById('amount');
div.innerHTML += "<div><input type='text' name='amount[]'  value ='' "+"id=amount"+count+"></div>";
div.innerHTML += "\n<br />";
var div = document.getElementById('discount');
div.innerHTML += "<div><input type='text' name='discount[]'  value ='' "+"id=discount"+count+"></div>";
div.innerHTML += "\n<br />";
}

function removeTextArea(){
document.getElementById("name"+count).remove();

document.getElementById("quantity"+count).remove();

document.getElementById("amount"+count).remove();

document.getElementById("discount"+count).remove();
count = count-1;
}

</script>


</head>

<body>

<form  action="invoicesubmit.php" method="POST">
<?php
echo "<table border='2'>\n"; 
echo "<tr>\n"; 
echo "<th>Description</th>\n"; 
echo "<th>Quantity</th>\n"; 
echo "<th>Amount($)</th>\n";
echo "<th>Discount(%)</th>\n";
echo "</tr>"; 

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>"?><input type='text' size="50" name='name[]' value='Examination and Consultation' readonly/><?php "</td>";
echo "<td>"?><input type='text' size="50" name='quantity[]' value='' /><?php "</td>";
echo "<td>"?><input type='text' size="50" name='amount[]' value='' /><?php "</td>";
echo "<td>"?><input type='text' size="50" name='discount[]' value='' /><?php "</td>";
echo "</tr>";

echo "<tr>"; 
echo "<td>"?><div id="name"></div> <?php "</td>"; 
echo "<td>"?><div id="quantity"></div> <?php "</td>"; 
echo "<td>"?><div id="amount"></div> <?php "</td>"; 
echo "<td>"?><div id="discount"></div> <?php "</td>"; 
echo "</tr>";
?>
<br />
<input type="button" value="Add Description" onClick="addTextArea();"> &nbsp;


<input type="button" value="Remove Description" onClick="removeTextArea();"> &nbsp;
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

invoicesubmit

```
<?php require_once("includes/session.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/db_connection.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/functions.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/validation_function.php"); ?>


<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // Process the form

    $name_array = $_POST['name'];
    $quantity_array = $_POST['quantity'];
    $amount_array = $_POST['amount'];
    $discount_array = $_POST['discount'];

    $total_amt_array = ($amount_array - ($amount_array * ($discount_array/ 100))) * $quantity_array ;

    for ($i =0; $i < count($name_array); $i++) {

        $name = $name_array[$i];
        $quantity = $quantity_array[$i];
        $amount = $amount_array[$i];
        $discount = $discount_array[$i];
        $total_amt = $total_amt_array[$i];

            echo $name;
    echo "<br />";
    echo $quantity;
    echo "<br />";
    echo $amount;
    echo "<br />";
    echo $discount;
    echo "<br />";
    echo $total_amt;
    }
}
/*  
    //validations
    $required_fields = array("name", "quantity", "amount", "discount");
    validate_presences($required_fields);

    $fields_with_max_lengths = array("name" => 200);
    validate_max_lengths($fields_with_max_lengths);



    if (!empty($errors)) {
      $_SESSION["errors"] = $errors;
      redirect_to("create_invoice.php");    
    }*/




        /*
    // 2. Perform database query
    $query = "INSERT INTO invoicesub (";
    $query .= " description, quantity, amount, discount, total";
    $query .= ") VALUES (";
    $query .= " '{$name}', '{$quantity}', '{$amount}', '{$discount}', '{$total}'";
    $query .= ")";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);



    if ($result) {
        // Success
        $_SESSION["message"] = "Subject created.";

        redirect_to("confirm_invoice.php");
    }


    else {
        // Failure
        $_SESSION["message"] = "Subject creation failed.";
        redirect_to("create_invoice.php");
    }


} else {
    // This is probably a GET request
    redirect_to("create_invoice.php");
} */
?>


<?php
   if (isset($connection)) { mysqli_close($connection); }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have:

```
echo "<td>"?><input type='text' size="50" name='amount[]' value='' /><?php "</td>";
                                                      ^^---create an array in $_POST
```

Then:

```
$amount_array = $_POST['amount'];
^^^^^^^^^^^----this is now an array
```

Then:

```
$total_amt_array = ($amount_array - ($amount_array * ($discount_array/ 100))) * $quantity_array ;
```

This code boils down to:

```
$total_amt_array = Array - (Array * (Array / 100))) * Array;
```

You cannot multiply/divide arrays in PHP.

Comment: Okay, any way of forming the formula for total_amt without the use of arrays?